# Can a Masonite route accept a parameter anywhere other than the end of a URL?

Tags: python, masonite

The [Masonite route documentation](https://docs.masoniteproject.com/the-basics/routing) describes passing a parameter at the end of a URL like so:

```
# Handles /article/1234
Route.get('/article/@id', 'ArticleController@show')
```

What I want to do is create a slug after the article.id, and just use the article.id to return the appropriate article from the database. The Masonite documentation doesn't seem to explain how to do this, but I guessed it'd look something like the below (which doesn't work).

```
# Handles /article/1234/my-nice-slug
Route.get('/article/@id/*', 'ArticleController@show')
```

Does anybody know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself.

You can grab the article.id by assigning the next part of the path another parameter and not using it. i.e:

```
# Handles /article/1234/my-nice-slug
Route.get('/article/@id/@my_slug', 'ArticleController@show')
```

**edit**

Joe Mancuso of Masonite also suggests using [route compilers](https://docs.masoniteproject.com/the-basics/routing#route-compilers).

Try `'/article/@id:integer/@my_slug'`

which would match `/article/123` but not `/article/string_here`